# Possible to force Codeigniter controller to handle direct link to file?

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

I have a feeling this isn't possible but thought I'd check anyway.

I have a directory called invoices in the webroot and inside that are directories for each user by id (22, 65 etc.) and inside each of these are the user's invoices with a random string name such as xy38yrv4629mg7.pdf.

What I'd like to do is have a controller called invoice pick up requests for
https://www.domain.tld/invoice/22/xy38yrv4629mg7.pdf so I can run a security check to ensure that user is allowed to download that file and then have CI give them the file for download. Is this possible or is it outside of CI's control?

I have a feeling the web server identifies the request as a file before CI even has a chance to initiate though. I can move the invoice directory out of the webfoot and do it that way but thought I'd definitively rule out this method first.

Comment: You should not call the file directly, but have a relation table where each file is given a unique code. When you call that code in the url, you verify if the user is allowed to fetch the file, and if it is, you read the file and write it out in the header response (prompting a download). I.E., _never_ disclose the filepath

Comment: I know and that's what I've got already, I'm just curious if the above is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the .htaccess file. There should be something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

These rules prevent existing files or directories from being rewritten to index.php.
Change it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css)$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

In this way the path to the pdf documents will be rewritten to your index.php frontcontroller. You will be able to register routes for the pdf documents and do checks before sending the document to the browser manually.

**Example:**

The physical path to the pdf document is `https://www.domain.tld/invoice/22/xy38yrv4629mg7.pdf`.

In CodeIgniter (I don't use it) the route should be:

```
$route['invoice/(:num)/(:any)'] = "invoice/download/$1/$2";
```

Now if you call the above path the method `download` with 2 parameters in the class `invoice` will be called.

```
$invoice->download(22, 'xy38yrv4629mg7.pdf');
```

In the method `download` you can do the user checks to prevent unauthorized access.

```
function download($userid, $pdfName)
{
    // check if file exists
    // do checks if logged in user is authorized
    // send file to browser with readfile/header        
}
```

Comment: Very cool. I think probably I'd use something more like
RewriteRule ^invoice/(.+)/(.+\.pdf)$ invoice/fetch [L] (syntax is off the top of my head, I'm no htaccess pro)!
as I wouldn't want to have to keep adding extensions for other files I may need to use in the future.

Comment: yes this is a good idea. I'm also no htaccess pro, so I can't tell you the exact syntax..but you get the idea and can build on that.

Comment: This is a bad idea. How will you prevent unauthorized users from accessing invoices?

Comment: @NeilGirardi with the `RewriteCond` above you will not be able to direct access all file types other than `(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css)`.

Comment: @redreggae Right, but if a route to a specific PDF exists how would you prevent unauthorized users from accessing it?

Comment: I've now implemented this (with my slight variation on the rewrite rule to only rewrite pdf files) and it is flawless. Thanks very much for this excellent solution, I hadn't even thought to try it in htaccess!

Answer (score 0):

By default, your CI app will interpret the segments in the incoming GET request as 'controller/action/id.' I don't think you want to alter that routing protocol. Doing so would defeat the purpose of using an MVC framework. It would also be laborious. Finally, it creates confusing legacy code.

Rather, I think you want to adapt your controller and methods to work with it. Does your app have user accounts? If so any method of any of your controllers can be set to check for a valid session. This method could be used to redirect unauthorized users to the home page. Once you've established that your user is logged in she should only need to supply a document ID to a getInvoice() method of your controller. You should be able to match that to the correct directory path and file name by doing joins across a relational database. Your .htacess file should prevent users from accessing random invoices by guessing at URLs and directory paths.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am quite familiar with CI and all your suggestions, I was more just wondering if it was possible to access the controller before attempting to serve the file. I created a route which forwarded requests for invoice/22/xyz.pdf to invoice/fetch/22/xyz.pdf but it always picks up the file before using the controller. I guess I'll have to stick with a relation table and store the invoices outside the webroot.

Comment: Yes, of course. I apologize for being "Captain Obvious." It seems that @redreggae has devised a rather clever solution. Please let us know how you make out. Cheers --n